# If else condition, that else condition should fail instead of pass in postman

Tags: postman

I want to write a if else condition so that if the value doesn't matches then it will go to else condition and i'm able to get that.

But the thing the test case is getting passed after going to else condition, but my requirement is that if the flow reaches else condition the test case should fail.

Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: Without showing any of the test code or an example of the fail, it's going to be impossible to see what you can in front of you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the context here so this is just a simple example of a test that fails if it goes down a certain path:

```
let a = 124

pm.test("Check that the value matches", () => {
    if (a === 123) {
        pm.expect(a).to.equal(123)
    }
    else {
        pm.expect.fail(`Value didn't equal 123 - Value was ${a}`)
    }
})
```

I created a variable `a` with the value `124` - The `if` condition is saying if `a` equals `123` go down this path and assert against that value. If it's anything else, it will show a fail using `pm.expect.fail()`.

[image]

Without knowing more about what you're trying to do, I can't comment about the *need* to have an `if/else` to fail a Test. If the assertion or `pm.expect()` statement is not met, it's going to fail the test for you and show the reason why in the Test Results:

```
let a = 124

pm.test("Check that the value matches", () => {
        pm.expect(a).to.equal(123)
})
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Danny. Thanks for the Post. I have figured out different ways to make the if else condition more useful in case of validating the responses. Your suggestion also matches my requirement. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I was going off extremely limited information to be fair :D Glad you found something that works for you.